# Fireebase Crashlitics -[NSDateFormatter _setDateFormat:alreadyLocked:]

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, nsdateformatter, crashlytics

I get
-[NSDateFormatter _setDateFormat:alreadyLocked:]

in my Firebase Crashlytics,

How it caused and how to fix it?

Is it a thread-safety issue?

Comment: What's the full error? It's unclear what's the issue. On which thread this is called?

Comment: I was not able to regenerate the crash, (it happen to users). I see this it Crashlytics: Crashed: com.apple.root.utility-qos
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x22747865746e6f43